# How do I install python 3.7.4 and pip to the path in windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, environment-variables

Python and pip wont work when added to the path

I've tried adding it to user variables and system variables and multiple different directories including the default location which is the option I chose when installing.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Turns out I had to uninstall py launcher and then go to installation setting for python and check add to path.